# "Return type" of <text> in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-helper

I'm trying to figure out how (or if it's possible) to write an HTML helper method that could be invoked in the following manner:

```
@Html.MyHelper("some string parameter", @<text>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>some html content in a "template" @Model.SomeProperty</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</text>)
```

The idea is to allow a user to create their own template to be passed to the helper.  With some poking around I came up with this code:

```
public static MvcHtmlString jQueryTmpl(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string templateId, Func<object, HelperResult> template) {
    return MvcHtmlString.Create("<script id='" + templateId + "' type='x-jquery-tmpl'>" + template.Invoke(null) + "</script>");
}
```

and this works, but I don't understand why or if it even makes sense.  Could someone explain what `<text>` actually is in the background and how could I use it in the context I described above?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The special `<text>` tag exists to allow you to force a transition from code to markup in cases where the Razor parser would normally choose code mode. For example the body of an `if` statement defaults to code mode:

```
@if(condition) {
    // still in code mode
}
```

The razor parser has logic to automatically switch to markup mode if it detects a tag:

```
@if(condition) {
    <div>Hello @Model.Name</div>
}
```

However you might want to switch to markup mode without actually emitting some tag (as the above case would emit the `<div>` tags). You can either use a `<text>` block or the `@:` syntax:

```
@if(condition) {
    // Code mode
    <text>Hello @Model.Name <!-- Markup mode --></text>
    // Code mode again
}

@if(condition) {
    // Code mode
    @:Hello @Model.Name<!-- Will stay in markup mode till end of line -->
    // Code mode again
}
```

So back to your question: in this case you don't need the `<text>` tag because your template already has tags that will trigger the correct behavior in Razor. You could just write:

```
@Html.MyHelper("some string parameter", @<table>
    <tr>
      <td>some html content in a "template" @Model.SomeProperty</td>
    </tr>
</table>)
```

The reason this works is because the Razor parser inside of a code context recognizes the `@<tag></tag>` pattern and converts it into a `Func<object, HelperResult>`.

In your example the generated code would look roughly like this:

```
Write(Html.MyHelper("some string parameter",item => new System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult(__razor_template_writer => {
    WriteLiteralTo(@__razor_template_writer, "<table>\r\n      <tr>\r\n        <td>some html content in a \"template\" ");
    WriteTo(@__razor_template_writer, Model.SomeProperty);
    WriteLiteralTo(@__razor_template_writer, "</td>\r\n      </tr>\r\n    </table>");
})));
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.  If I understand correctly, `<text>` is then just a "fake" tag that helps Razor understand my intentions, but will not be displayed with the resulting HTML, while the `<table>` in your example would show up in the output as it is a "real" tag.

Comment: Yes, `<text>` is just indeed just a fake tag.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I've been looking for this.